# how to enable https connections in phpstorm's built in web server

Tags: phpstorm

My php application has to work over https. However phpstorm's build in web server does not serve https connections.

I even enabled two different built in web servers over ports 80 and 443, but `https://localhost` does not work while `http://localhost` works.

How to configure built in web server for https?

Comment: AFAIK built-in **simple** web server does not support HTTPS protocol (regardless on what port you will run it).

Answer (score 1):

The PHP built-in webserver has zero support for SSL.  There are a few ways to fake it, none of them good.  The idea seems to be that a development server (which it is intended to be) has no need of SSL, but someone clearly overlooked the need to develop handling and the like for SSL based connections.

A simple example would be Wordpress running with the `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` flag set to true.

If your development requires it I suggest installing a more robust webserver for your development.